# Who are these characters who have appeared for one episode each?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-identification

A few weeks ago I found the following image on reddit and saved it with means to coming back later to identify who all the characters were. I subsequently forgot about it and lost the link to the reddit thread. According to the the redditor who posted the image each character has apparently only appeared in one episode each.

Do we know who the characters are?

[image: One episode wonders]

Comment: Sheeran alone merits the downvote...

Comment: @TheMathemagician So the show casting Ed Sheeran means I get a downvote? Yeah makes sense.

Comment: +1, because some people are just salty crabs. We want fermented crab, not salty crabs!

Comment: What's special about this image? Did someone just put images of random characters together?

Comment: @Mart10 I believe they titled it something like "The best one episode characters".

Comment: Could it be that those characters are notable because they are **cameos** played by famous actors/people? The Septon is played by Ian McShane, the wildling woman by Birgitte Hjort Sørensen, then there is Ed Sheeran, ... (possibile exception: the wight, but maybe he was motion-captured by someone famous too?)

Comment: @lfurini Nice idea but I can’t remember that being mentioned in the reddit post. Also as far as I know only the three you commented on are actually cameos, I don’t think the other three are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Top Left: [Ray](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ray)

He is the Septon in season 6 episdoe 7, "The Broken Man", who had previously saved Sandor Clegane and nursed him back to health. Him and his followers are building a sept with the help of Sandor. Later on three riders from The Brotherhood Without Banners attack the group whilst Sandor is off in the woods and kill everyone. Sandor finds Ray has been hung in the unfinished sept.

#### Middle Left: [Karsi](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Karsi)

She is a wildling spearwife in season 5 episode 8, "Hardhome", she stays to defend the boats and to try and get more people evacuated. During this defense she is attacked by wight children and is unable to attack them, they overcome her and she is killed. Moments later she is raised as a wight by the Night King.

#### Bottom Left: Eddard Sheeran ([Lannister soldier 1](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Lannister_soldier_1_(Dragonstone)))

He is a Lannister soldier in season 7 episdoe 1, "Dragonstone", that Arya Stark runs into round a campfire. They have been sent to the Riverlands to keep the peace, he sings Hands of Gold round the campfire.

#### Top Right: Wight #2,199,367

He is the wight in season 7 episode 6, "Beyond the Wall", that Sandor Clegane throws a rock at and takes his jaw off. This is the first wight to start the advance across the frozen lake and so is presumably dead-dead.

#### Bottom Middle: [Mycah](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mycah)

He is the butchers boy in season 1 episode 2, "The Kingsroad", who Arya Stark befriends and practices her Needlework with. He is killed by The Hound later in the episode.

#### Bottom Right: [Kinvara](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kinvara)

She appears in season 6 episode 5, "The Door", and is the Red Priestess that Tyrion Lannister and Varys meet with in Meereen to convince the locals to follow Daenerys Targaryen.

Comment: Dunno about Weight #2199367 being dead dead. Dumb Khant as I like to call him was last seen pulling Sandor into the icy water. White he was down there he probably helped attach those chains to Viceron. I hope he makes an appearance in the next episode

Comment: @MikeyMouse - To your point, (and it's likely another question altogether), but can the Wights ever be "dead-dead"? Even if they fell in the bottom of the ocean, would they just wander down there forever? (Or, perhaps, until the "lead Wight" is killed?)

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes through fire, dragonglass or Valyrian steel. Or until the White Walker who turned them is killed.

Comment: Also might be interesting to add how some of these one-offs were important to the plot or main character arcs.  Like Sandor finding Ray dead led him to rejoin the fight, Sandor killing Mycah led to Arya forming her list (maybe not the only event, but certainly a significant one), Sandor throwing the rock at the wight and knocking it's jaw off caused it to take a step forward which led to all the wights realizing the frozen lake was traversable and beginning their advance, etc.  For Sheeran... I got nothin'. Cameo value only.

Comment: @BruceWayne Fun fact: All of the aforementioned ways are available to the Fellowship of the Wight at the time wight #2,199,367 starts to approach the group.